# expect script with optional ssh-agent passphrase prompt?

Tags: ssh, expect, ssh-agent

I want to automate a database backup with help from *expect*: First, the script establishes a forwarded port from the remote database port to my local machine using *ssh*. Then I use the database utility to dump all databases.

Therefore, I have the following *expect* script inside a *bash* script:

```
#!/bin/sh

expect <<- DONE
  set timeout -1

  # port-forward remote database port 3306 to local port 3307
  spawn ssh -M -S /var/run/examplecom-mysql-socket -fnNT -L 3307:localhost:3306 someuser@example.com

  expect {
    # conditional prompt appears in case ssh-agent is not active
    "*.ssh/id_rsa':*" {
      send -- "$SSH_PASSPHRASE\r"
    }
    # ?!?!?!? What to expect here in case ssh-agent is active, therefore no password needed, and therefore no prompt appears?
  }

  # dump remote database by connecting to forwarded port
  spawn mysqldump --all-databases --user=root --password --protocol=TCP --host=localhost --port=3307 --verbose --result-file=${DB_DUMP_FILE}

  expect {
    # prompt appears for database password 
    "*?asswor?:*" {
    send -- "$PASSWORD_MYSQL_ROOT\r"      
    }
  }

  expect eof
DONE
```

This script may run within two scenarios:

- Either *ssh-agent* is currently not active. In that case, the spawned *ssh* process will prompt `Enter passphrase for key '${HOME}/.ssh/id_rsa':`, which the first *expect* rule happily matches, and correctly sends the SSH passphrase.
- Or *ssh-agent* is currently active. In that case, the spawned *ssh* process silently establishes the port forwarding and does not need or prompt for the SSH passphrase.

I am struggling to get both scenarios working in my expect script. In particular, I don't know how to modify the script so that the "silent" active-ssh-agent is "expected" and therefore the expect script can continue with  starting the database dump.

I tried the *expect multiple things* approach (at above `?!?!?!?` comment location) by trying out:

- expecting a newline,
- expecting my shell prompt,
- expecting `eof`.

But none worked. I found similar problems and suggested solutions around StackExchange:
* [How to use expect with optional prompts?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17621050/923560)
* https://superuser.com/q/412259/137881
* [TCL / Expect Scripting - Using a conditional statement to attempt a secondary login password](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11332920/923560)

But the solutinos seem to cause code duplications: Each conditional prompt means copy and pasting the rest of the script, which makes the script get convoluted quickly with nested conditional prompts for each ssh statement.

How can I have *expect* work gracefully in situations where *ssh* does not prompt for the passphrase/password because of an active ssh-agent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, that's a funny one. Since you're using ssh `-N`, you don't launch any process on the remote host, and the ssh session just sits there. You would just have to sleep for a couple of seconds and hope the tunnel gets established.

```
set timeout 2
spawn ssh -M -S /var/run/examplecom-mysql-socket -fnNT -L 3307:localhost:3306 someuser@example.com

expect {
    # conditional prompt appears in case ssh-agent is not active
    "*.ssh/id_rsa':*" { send -- "$SSH_PASSPHRASE\r" }
    # wait until the timeout, then carry on with the rest of the script
    timeout
}

set timeout -1
# ...
```

Or, remove `-N`, then you can expect to see the prompt on the remote host.

```
spawn ssh -M -S /var/run/examplecom-mysql-socket -fnT -L 3307:localhost:3306 someuser@example.com
# ..........................................^^^^

expect {
    # conditional prompt appears in case ssh-agent is not active
    "*.ssh/id_rsa':*" { send -- "$SSH_PASSPHRASE\r" }
    # I assume your prompt ends with a dollar sign and a space
    -re {\$ $}
}
```

Now you can spawn the mysql command and interact with that.

Comment: Awesome! Your `timeout` suggestion did the trick. The answer version from 2016-03-04 relies on the assumption that the port forward will definitely be established before timeout. To not depend on this assumption, I have expanded it with `timeout {
      if {[file exists /var/run/examplecom-mysql-socket]} {
        send_user "file exists... continuing\r"
      } else {
        send_user "file does not exist. This implies ssh port could not be established. Quitting script\r"
        exit 2
      }`, thereby quitting in case the socket (file) `/var/run/examplecom-mysql-socket` wasn't established.